# Elasticsearch log explanation

Tags: logging, request, elasticsearch

I have enabled the slowlog for my elasticsearch server to see the traffic I get on it.

Here is some example output:

```
[2013-07-23 06:10:45,213][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [Afari, Jamal] [index_3559_schema1][4] took[107.5micros], took_millis[0], types[some_type], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[195], source[{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"*"}},"from":0,"size":"24","sort":{"updated_at":"desc"}}], extra_source[],
[2013-07-23 06:10:45,214][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [Afari, Jamal] [index_3559_schema1][3] took[155.6micros], took_millis[0], types[some_type], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[195], source[{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"*"}},"from":0,"size":"24","sort":{"updated_at":"desc"}}], extra_source[],
[2013-07-23 06:10:45,214][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [Afari, Jamal] [index_3559_schema1][2] took[107.7micros], took_millis[0], types[some_type], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[195], source[{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"*"}},"from":0,"size":"24","sort":{"updated_at":"desc"}}], extra_source[],
...
[2013-07-22 15:10:45,260][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.fetch] [Afari, Jamal] [index_42044_schema1][3] took[85.3micros], took_millis[0], types[some_type], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[195], source[{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"*"}},"from":0,"size":"24","sort":{"updated_at":"desc"}}], extra_source[],
```

Does each of those lines mean (`index_3559_schema1, index_3559_schema1, index_3559_schema1`) I had an separate HTTP request?

What is the difference between `index.search.slowlog.query` and `index.search.slowlog.fetch`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slowlog doesn't refer to http requests but to queries, on the shard level. That means that if you query an index composed of 5 shards you'll have in the log 5 entries for the same query, one per shard, with a different shard id, which is the number that appears right after the index name. That way you can monitor the execution of each query for each shard.

The fetch line refers to the fetch phase. By default the query_then_fetch [search type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/search-type/) is used, which means that if you query an index composed of 5 primary shards (let's assume 0 replica to make it simpler), the query will be executed on each shard, which will return only the relevant information like the document ids and their scores. The node that you hit with your search request will then reduce those results in order to return only the top ones. After the reduce part that identifies which documents need to be returned, only those relevant documents are then fetched from their shard. That's when you see the fetch phase in your slowlog.

Comment: Is it possible to tell if the 3 first logs from my example came from different requests?

Comment: Not given those single lines, but you can make assumptions looking at what happened around the same time. Every query to an index (the type doesn't play any role here) will hit all of its shards (unless you specify a routing). If you have the same query that hit for instance 5 shards and the queried index is made of 5 shards, well you can say that was a single http request.

Comment: And of course if you have multiple searches on the same index and same shard, those were most likely caused by different http requests.